# Assigning first candle previous color background

Tags: pine-script, moving-average, trading, trend

I have this simple code that shows the long term trend of price with the integration of a Bollinger Band to have an exclusion zone.

Price though, might be entering briefly this band to then exit it again on the next candle, so I'd like to add another option that the first candle in the band retains the same background color of the previous candle.

It's probably a very easy solution but I guess it's still out of my grasp.

TIA

[image: as in this example]

```
//@version=4
study(title="200SMA vs Price", shorttitle="MAvsP", overlay=false)
len = 200
src = close
out200 = sma(src, len)
plot(out200, color=color.blue, title="200SMA", linewidth=2)

mult = input(5.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50, title="StdDev", step=1)
dev = mult/10 * stdev(src, len)
upper = out200 + dev
lower = out200 - dev

plot(src, color=color.black, title="Price", linewidth=2)

bgcolor( (src > upper) ? #00FF00 :
         (src < lower) ? #FF0000 : 
         (src > lower) and (src < upper) ? #FFFF00 :
         na, transp=70)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bgcolor( (src > upper or (src[1] > upper[1] and (src > lower) and (src < upper))) ? #00FF00 :
         (src < lower or (src[1] < lower[1] and (src > lower) and (src < upper))) ? #FF0000 : 
         (src > lower) and (src < upper) ? #FFFF00 :
         na, transp=70)
```

Preservation of color on the first candle when entering the channel.

Comment: That's a nice easy solution to the problem. Thank you! 

Only thing would be that in this case it would still show me a green background on a candle if price would go directly from above the upper band to the below the lower one without stopping within the band. Any solution around this?

Comment: What color should be in case  "if price would go directly from above the upper band to the below the lower one without stopping within the band"?

Comment: You also need to determine what color will be if the candle comes out and returns to the channel.
You need to consider all possible options for the movement of candles through the channel.

Comment: Yes, you are right. What I was thinking was to have candles closing above the channel having green background, in the channel in yellow, below the channel in red, and having the condition that a temporary movement from the outside to the inside of the channel or viceversa to not be recorded. Movement from one side to another without "stopping" in the channel can be unrestricted. The main idea is to have 3 main colors without having too much noise cause by temporary movements.

Comment: Updated the script in the answer.